# using variables in a Terraform destroy provisioner

Tags: terraform

In the past I have managed to work around the limitation of not being able to use variables inside a destroy provisioner by using things such as terraform.workspace, per the error message you get when attempting to use variables, you can also use 'self', 'count.index', or 'each.key'. I've only ever seen self used in the context of referencing values from a map associated with a triggers block of a null_resource, however what I want to reference, a URL and API token aren't applicable for use inside a triggers block. Is there some elegant way I'm missing of working around this limitation ?.

Comment: "what I want to reference, a URL and API token aren't applicable for use inside a triggers block" Why?

Comment: I don’t think they are applicable in the specific context of my use case, I’m guessing I could put them into the triggers block regardless ?

Comment: Have you tried it, what were the results, and what does the config look like?

Comment: I've tried it self.triggers.x gives me the values of things after they have changed, I need the value before the thing in the triggers map has changed